# Derived apk from google play console not working but original apk working perfectly

Tags: android, ionic3, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I have uploaded (updated) my apk in google play console. After upload to google play I just download it from play store and installed. It crash when I try to open the app.

My app created in ionic 3.

It not working only after I upload into google play.

My SHA1 certificate are also properly presented.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.Application: com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MessageGuardException_RFA6IDMwNA: DP: 304 (RmluZ2VycHJpbnQgMjAxOTA3MDIgWy4rKysrLl0gYXJtZWFiaS12N2E6YXJtZWFiaS12N2EgMjYvMi4xLjAvLSBtb3Rvcm9sYS9hbGkvYWxpOjguMC4wL09QUzI3LjgyLTQ1LzU2OnVzZXIvcmVsZWFzZS1rZXlz)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5838)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1674)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
 Caused by: com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MessageGuardException_RFA6IDMwNA: DP: 304 (RmluZ2VycHJpbnQgMjAxOTA3MDIgWy4rKysrLl0gYXJtZWFiaS12N2E6YXJtZWFiaS12N2EgMjYvMi4xLjAvLSBtb3Rvcm9sYS9hbGkvYWxpOjguMC4wL09QUzI3LjgyLTQ1LzU2OnVzZXIvcmVsZWFzZS1rZXlz)
    at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.Application.onCreate(Unknown Source:169)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5835)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1674) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: DP: 304
    at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.Application$Application.wuxig(Unknown Source:690)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.Application$Application.Honlx(Unknown Source:99)
    at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.Application$Application.loqunIlzz(Unknown Source:201)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.Application.onCreate(Unknown Source:117)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1674) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
```

So i download my apk from google play console. I have two apks in there, **derived apk** and **original apk**.

What is different between two? 
My original apk works well but derived apk crash. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have some anti-tampering mechanism in place that checks either the integrity of the AndroidManifest.xml file or verifies the certificate your app is signed with.

Because your app is enrolled in App Signing by Play, Play adds one meta-data in the manifest and re-signs your APK (that's the "derived APK"), and it seems that the anti-tampering library you're using is not friendly to this practice thus crashes when detects one of these modifications.

If you use dexguard, make sure to use a version past 8.3: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/dexguard-83-released

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am not using dexgurad. It works well in earlier release. Now I just changed targetsdkversion to 29. Does it cause any issue?

Comment: Is com.gae.scaffolder.plugin your package name? This is the code that is throwing the exception, so knowing what it is would help.

Comment: That package contain fcm plugin code. If I delete fcm plugin, again this error raise with Cordova- plugin-notificatin

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I find solution here "https://dexprotector.com/node/4267#googke-signing"

Comment: Ah, so you _were_ using an anti-tampering mechanism! Btw, that link does not work.

Comment: This seems to be the right link for whoever finds this: https://dexprotector.com/docs#google-signing

Comment: Yes. That anti-tampering happens after google re-sign it in google play

Comment: And you re-upload the protected APK to google play? That seems like an unnecessary roundtrip.

Comment: Yes I changed my version code. Now I protect my apk by above mentioned dexprotector steps, then upload into google play